# jquery :: how to store and send this data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

basically I have a for loop that give me two values,

id, and value on each loop

now,

I have no idea what either of the values will be.

Anyway

there can be an unlimited number of these.

But I need to store them in a way that I can send them using jquery's ajax.

in a way that on the other end (in php),

I can loop over them in a simple `foreach` loop

I was thinking json but have no idea how to create the json object in the javascript for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply store them in an object

```
var data = {};
for (/* your for loop */) {
    // get "id" and "value" vars
    data[id] = value;
}

$.post('processor.php', data);
```

Then in your PHP file, loop over the `$_POST` array

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    foreach ($_POST as $id => $value) {
        // tada
    }
}
```

Edit: If you wanted to isolate the id/value data from other post data, you could build a named post data array like so

```
var data = {};
for (/* your for loop */) {
    // get "id" and "value" vars

    var key = "dataValues[" + id + "]";
    data[key] = value;
}

$.post('processor.php', data);
```

And process it like this

```
if (isset($_POST['dataValues']) && is_array($_POST['dataValues']) {
    foreach ($_POST['dataValues'] as $id => $value) {
        // tada
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for ( var x in someArray ) {
    data = {id : x, value : someArray[x]};
    $.get(URL, data);
}
```

Comment: That's going to fire off an AJAX request for each id => value combo individually

Comment: "I was thinking json but have no idea how to create the json object in the javascript for loop."
Merely answered that question Phil, as to its efficiency its disgusting.